# Сравнить пользовательский список и список списков (сравнение списков разной длины) Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список списков:

```
p = [
     [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1], 
     [4, 5, 6], [4, 6, 5], [5, 4, 6], [5, 6, 4], [6, 4, 5], [6, 5, 4], 
     [7, 8, 9], [7, 9, 8], [8, 7, 9], [8, 9, 7], [9, 7, 8], [9, 8, 7], 
     [7, 4, 1], [7, 1, 4], [4, 7, 1], [4, 1, 7], [1, 7, 4], [1, 4, 7], 
     [8, 5, 2], [8, 2, 5], [5, 8, 2], [5, 2, 8], [2, 8, 5], [2, 5, 8], 
     [9, 6, 3], [9, 3, 6], [6, 9, 3], [6, 3, 9], [3, 9, 6], [3, 6, 9], ....
    ]
```

Есть пользовательский ввод по одной цифре (то есть в начале список пустой, потом там один элемент и дальше еще один, еще, еще...)

```
p_ot_p=[1,8,5,2]
```

Вот, в списке p есть [8,5,2] и в вводе есть [..,8,5,2] каким методом дать пайтону понять, что это совпадение? Да, и p_ot_p=[8,5,1,2] и остальные вариации тоже являются совпадением :(
Подскажите алгоритм, чтобы найти совпадение, пожалуйста.
Можете прям меня загрузить, не писать код

Спасибо!

Comment: Порядок элементов не важен (то есть `p_ot_p = [2, 5, 8, 1]` тоже будет совпадением)?

Comment: Да, будет совпадением! Поздно правку внес.

Comment: как вариант, если элементы в списках уникальны (не повторяются), то можно работать с ними как с множествами и использовать для проверки совпадений метод `issubset`

Comment: `print(list(filter({8,5,2}.issubset, p)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если порядок элементов не важен, то можно обратить пользовательский список в множество (`set`), затем пройтись по каждому шестому списку исходного списка `p` и также обратить его во множество (остальные пять дадут такой же результат-множество), а затем сравнивать вхождение пользовательского множества и исходным при помощи [`issubset()`](https://pythonz.net/references/named/sets.issubset/) либо `<=` (да, можно проверять на включение при помощи арифметических знаков =) )

```py
p = [...] # исходный список
# получаем значения для p_ot_p
p_ot_p = [...] # Ваш список

set_p_ot_p = set(p_ot_p) # Ваш список стал множеством уникальных элементов
for index in range(0, len(p), 6): # проходим по каждому шестому подсписку
    lst_set = set(p[index])
    if lst_set.issubset(set_p_ot_p): # если все элементы очередн. множества входят в пользовательское,
        # то выводим информацию об этом
```

Comment: каждый 6ой, это очередная магия пайтона?

Comment: @VsevoloadPolu4ayka да нет, в C++, Java, C# и прочих языках также можно пропускать определённые элементы и брать N-ые (`for (int index = 0; index < p.Length; index += 6)`)